# elm IDE (editor and elm-reactor browser)

Tags: elm

Hi I am looking for a split screen IDE for elm. Just an editor on one side and a browser on the other running elm-reactor. I know I can position vi running in a text window and a browser in the other window, but this takes time and is fiddly, I am always having to adjust and find these screens after watching a video. Is there a nice simple IDE that I can start up to do this. The online try elm site is good (http://elm-lang.org/try), but I loose my code when I leave the web site. Ideally I'd like to run elm-reactor with an online editor locally on my machine. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an [Elm Plug-in for LightTable](https://github.com/rundis/elm-light) that you may like. The [demo](http://rundis.github.io/blog/2015/elm_light.html) shows that you can have tabs for editing code and tabs for running the web browser, all within the [LightTable IDE](http://lighttable.com/).

You could also set up the [Atom](https://atom.io) editor to run a web browser in a separate tab. There is an [Atom Elm Plugin](https://atom.io/packages/language-elm) which will give you syntax highlighting and [Elm Oracle](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-oracle) support.

There are a few online editors but these are really only good for small bits of Elm code, useful for testing and sharing small ideas, but not much else.

- [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/) - This allows the import of any public package, editing the html which wraps an Elm example, and links and forks of examples.
- [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try) - As you mentioned, this does not allow sharing of code. It does, however, include a few non-core packages like [StartApp](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/latest/StartApp)
- [share-elm.com](http://www.share-elm.com/) - *This site is now defunct* <s>This site has the benefit of being able to save code for sharing, or for loading gists. However, as of 2016-01-20, this has not been updated to Elm version 0.16, and it only allows you to import core libraries.</s>

I would be remiss if I didn't mention ElmCast's [elm-vim plugin for Vim](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-vim), and [elm-mode for Emacs](https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode), both of which offer syntax highlighting and Elm Oracle support, as well as integration with Elm build tools. They don't have a built-in web browser, but with a little configuration, you can certainly streamline your workflow.

Answer (score 5):

...and there is an Elm Plugin for the sophisticated IDEs from Jetbrains like IntelliJ, WebStorm etc.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8192-elm-language-plugin

Most of them are commercial software but there is an open source edition from IntelliJ: IntelliJ Community Edition and also free licenses for education and OSS projects.

For just writing Elm I like Atom Editor with the plugins language-elm, elm-oracle and linter-elm-make.

Comment: As. of 2023 it is 404, not found

Answer (score 5):

I really like the elm packages for [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

With them it is easy to get auto-complete, and auto-formanting/compilation on save, with compile errors displayed on the code.